# undefined method `new_customer_id' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a braintree_customer_id column at my users table. And I want to access it  with the following active_subscription method. But it's returning an error `undefined method braintree_customer_id for nil:NilClass` at the first line of the active_subscription method.

sessions_controller.rb

```
def active_subscription
 customer_id = current_client.braintree_customer_id
 customer = Braintree::Customer.find(customer_id )
 customer_card = customer.payment_methods[0].token
 payment_method = Braintree::PaymentMethod.find(customer_card)
 sub = payment_method.subscriptions[0]
 sub.status

 if Braintree::Subscription::Status::Active
   current_client.update(is_active: sub.status == Braintree::Subscription::Status::Active)
 end
```

end

```
def current_client
  if cookies["email"].present?
   Store.find_by_email(params[:email])
  end
end
```

Kind of new to rails, so help is very much appreciated on solving this one!

**Update 1**

I try to sign-in and is_active column in stores is still not updated.

```
Started POST "/stores/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-22 15:20:37 +0300
Processing by Stores::SessionsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Xfdn28k5YfgzPokr5vGtPsBAV5K10B0+ndNoY9Vxq0C3Tw5hhmpvm7DRU4N79wCEXDuLzhuYWllh7B1N1fmYRg==", "store"=>{"email"=>"example@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Log in"}
Store Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "stores".* FROM "stores" WHERE "stores"."email" = ? ORDER BY "stores"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["email", "example@gmail.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
(0.1ms)  begin transaction
(0.0ms)  commit transaction
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 180ms (ActiveRecord: 1.3ms)


Started GET "/stores/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-22 15:20:37 +0300
Processing by Stores::SessionsController#new as HTML
Rendering stores/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application
Rendered stores/shared/_links.html.erb (1.1ms)
Rendered stores/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (4.9ms)

[31, 40] in  /Users/theopap/RubymineProjects/prices/app/controllers/stores/sessions_controller.rb
 31:      end
 32:    end
 33: 
 34:    def active_subscription
 35:      byebug
 => 36:      if current_client.present?
 37:        customer_id = current_client.braintree_customer_id
 38:        customer = Braintree::Customer.find(customer_id )
 39:        customer_card = customer.payment_methods[0].token
 40:        payment_method =   Braintree::PaymentMethod.find(customer_card)

Store Load (4.6ms)  SELECT  "stores".* FROM "stores" WHERE "stores"."email" IS NULL LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]

[244, 253] in /Users/theopap/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb
244:             callback_sequence.after do |env|
245:               unless env.halted
246:                 user_callback.call env.target, env.value
247:               end
248: 
=> 249:               env
250:             end
251:           end
252:           private_class_method :halting
253: 
(byebug) next
next

[506, 515] in /Users/theopap/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb
506:         def invoke_before(arg)
507:           @before.each { |b| b.call(arg) }
508:         end
509: 
510:         def invoke_after(arg)
=> 511:           @after.each { |a| a.call(arg) }
512:         end
513:       end
514: 
515:       # An Array with a compile method.
(byebug) next
next

[128, 137] in /Users/theopap/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb
128:         # Common case: no 'around' callbacks defined
129:         if next_sequence.final?
130:           next_sequence.invoke_before(env)
131:           env.value = !env.halted && (!block_given? || yield)
132:           next_sequence.invoke_after(env)
=> 133:           env.value
134:         else
135:           invoke_sequence.call
136:         end
137:       end
(byebug) next
next

[28, 37] in /Users/theopap/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.2/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb
28:        ActiveSupport::Notifications.instrument("start_processing.action_controller", raw_payload.dup)
29: 
30:        ActiveSupport::Notifications.instrument("process_action.action_controller", raw_payload) do |payload|
31:         begin
32:           result = super
=> 33:           payload[:status] = response.status
34:           result
35:         ensure
36:           append_info_to_payload(payload)
37:         end
```

I also have the following inside store.rb in order to block store if not active!

```
def inactive_message
  "Store not active, please subscribe!"
end

def active_for_authentication?
  super && is_active?
end
```

Comment: That error means you don't have a current_client (because you're not logged in or whatever). Anticipate and handle that situation.

Comment: `current_client` is *nil*. How did you set up `current_client`?

Comment: @Pavan: it's literally two lines below :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Haha literally missed it :D

Comment: I'm trying to set current client thru email cookie via the above method, I can't use the current_user helper because the userr is not logged in, I'm trying to validate if account is active before the user can log-in.

Comment: @Devup: so far your code only handles the happy path, where the account is active. You should also handle the other situation, where it's inactive.

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev... I am, please check the def activate method in question, I updated it.

Comment: @Devup: no, you aren't. What if `cookies['email']` isn't there?

Comment: @Devup: also that `if` condition will not work as you intend it to.

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev...hmmm you're right.... any suggestions on how to fix the error and implement the inactive situation?

Comment: @Devup : Check I have just post my answer

Comment: @Devup: code-wise handling this is as simple as checking value of `current_client`. If it's nil, do one thing. If not, do another. As to what _exactly_ you should do when it's nil, I don't have a slightest idea. That's your app and your logic.

Answer (score 0):

> undefined method new_customer_id for nil:NilClass

above error indicates that your `current_client` is `nil` so you can't get `new_customer_id` change your code like below:

```
def activate
  if current_client.present?
    customer_id = current_client.new_customer_id
    customer = Braintree::Customer.find(customer_id )
    customer_card = customer.payment_methods[0].token
    payment_method = Braintree::PaymentMethod.find(customer_card)
    sub = payment_method.subscriptions[0]
    sub.status

    if Braintree::Subscription::Status::Active
      current_client.update_attributes(is_active: sub.status == Braintree::Subscription::Status::Active)
    end
  else
    # here you need to place the code to handle this case (current_client not found)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks @Gagan Gami, I'm not getting the error now!! But not sure if the whole activate method is working correctly, since the is_active column doesn't seem to get updated for some reason!! Any ideas?

Comment: @Devup : instead of `update` method use `update_attributes` it will update the object

Comment: Nope, still not updating the object for some reason

Comment: @Devup : use this gem in development env to debug code line by line  https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/pry-byebug

Comment: I just diid @Gagan Gami, please check update 1 for more details!

Comment: type `next` and hit enter to debug to next line

Comment: Sorry about that @Gagan Game, I did hit next a few times!

Comment: It cant find the current_client.... am I reading this right @Gagan Game? `Store Load (4.6ms)  SELECT  "stores".* FROM "stores" WHERE "stores"."email" IS NULL LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]`

Comment: @Devup: Can you please describe me what you want? and how? explain me the whole flow.

Comment: @Devup : Issue is you are not getting `current_client` but what you want to handle this `case if current_client` not found